# Getting unexpected error using fetch() in the dev tools

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, console, fetch

---

```
let getData = async(url)=>{

let response = await fetch(url);
let data = await response.json();
console.table(data);

}
getData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
```

---

### When I run the above code in  the console of chrome or egde browser it throws an error message saying

```
GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos net::ERR_FAILED
```

---

But when I run the same code through the script of an html document it does not throw any errors and works as expected, which is, it logs the JSON data received in a table format in the console.

Can someone explain why it's throwing that error when running from the console but no errors when i put it in the script of a HTML document?

Comment: I tried your code in chrome and edge's console, and it worked fine for me. Did not receive any error.

Comment: There is no problem in your code, there maybe some technical issue, like no internet connection etc...